# Find all pointers storing a particular address

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

While debugging in Visual Studio is there any way to find all pointers pointing to a particular address if it is known that they are within the present scope ?

Comment: no idea, but a slightly hacky approach could be to delete the object pointed to and see where the program falls over. that might give you a rough indication.

Comment: @dr.mo: You're kidding, right?  Use after free is notorious for causing the failure to appear in completely unrelated code.

Comment: that's why i said it _might_ give you a _rough_ indication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For VS2010, you can use a macro.

1. Open Macro window by clicking "Tools -> Macros -> Macro IDE".
2. Copy and paste the following macro

   ```
   Imports System
   Imports EnvDTE
   Imports EnvDTE80
   Imports EnvDTE90
   Imports EnvDTE90a
   Imports EnvDTE100
   Imports System.Diagnostics   
   Public Module Module1    
       Sub DumpLocals()
           Dim outputWindow As EnvDTE.OutputWindow
           Dim address As String = "0x009efedc"

           outputWindow = DTE.Windows.Item(EnvDTE.Constants.vsWindowKindOutput).Object
           Dim currentStackFrame As EnvDTE.StackFrame
           currentStackFrame = DTE.Debugger.CurrentStackFrame
           outputWindow.ActivePane.OutputString("*Dumping Local Variables*" + vbCrLf)
           For Each exp As EnvDTE.Expression In currentStackFrame.Locals
               If exp.Value = address Then
                   outputWindow.ActivePane.OutputString("Match: " + exp.Name + " = " + exp.Value.ToString() + vbCrLf)
               End If
           Next
       End Sub    
   End Module
   ```

   [image]
3. Set a breakpoint in your C++ program where you want to list the pointers.
4. Run your C++ program.
5. When the breakpoint is hit
6. Go back to the Macro window.
7. Change the value of the address variable in the macro. Note that you may need to remove the "0x" if you are not using hex.
8. Press Ctrl+S to save the macro.
9. While still in the Macro window, press F5 to run the macro. The result will be in the Output window (Debug -> Windows -> Output). 
   Maybe you can even add parameter to the macro and call it from Immediate Window.

**P/S**: This macro is modified from http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/18/debugging-tips-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Comment: hey answer mutated to explain a little more :)

Answer (score 1):

Err, I have another easier solution for you. When you hit a breakpoint:

1. Open the Locals window (Debug -> Windows -> Locals).
2. Press Ctrl+A to select everything in Locals window.
3. Press Ctrl+C to copy
4. Paste them into Excel
5. Sort the Value column in Excel.
6. Look for the matched pointers.